Quotient module is complete with the induced topology
Let $M$ be a complete filtered topological module and $N=M/P$ be a quotient of $M$. How can we show that $N$ is also complete?
We need to show that given the map $M\to \hat M$ from $M$ to its completion is a surjective morphism, so is the map $N\to \hat N$. The filtration on $N$ is given by $N_n=(M_n+P)/P$ and that is pretty much all that I have. How to proceed?
